# Is querying on foreign key faster than querying on regular integer columns?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a graph of items with columns: Id:identity, TargetId:foreign key.

I'm doing a recursive CTE query with for example `WHERE TargetId = @id` and `JOIN graph ON graph.SourceId = relationships.TargetId` etc.

Is the fact that TargetId is a foreign key affecting the performance of my query or could I just as well use an integer or perhaps a decimal? I mean if I'm not so interested in making sure that all TargetId's point to an existing item.

I'm asking because I have good reasons to move the TargetId into a generic property-table and making it an integer/decimal-valued property instead.

But if this would affect the performance in a bad way I would not do that of course.

Comment: check the execution plan of your query.

Comment: I understand that TargetId is not numeric, changing it to *int* and indexing it, would improve performance a lot, it probably will help use index seek and each row will take only 4 bytes. Furthermore if you move the TargetId property to a property table, you must look for database wide impact not for just one query.

Comment: Just because it's a foreign key doesn't (positively) impact query performance at all. It's only when you follow the **SQL Server** (assuming you said *SQL* but ***really*** meant **SQL Server**) best practices to put an index on every foreign key -> *then* you will see an improvement (and that's exactly why it *is* a recommended best practice to put an index on every foreign key column)